# Delete without warning any sheet for which the name contains the word "sheet"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small piece of VBA code here which  Deletes the worksheet called “Sheet1” Without Warning. What I would like that my code do is to delete without warning any worksheet containing in its name the word “Sheet” (for example: 1000Sheet, 10Sheet,Sheet2,Sheet3…Sheet1000…)

```
Sub ActShtDel()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to iterate over all the worksheets, check the name contains "Sheet" and if so, delete the worksheet in question.  This should do what you need

```
Sub ActShtDel()
Dim ws
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(ws.Name, "Sheet") > 0 Then
        ws.Delete
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Could do with checking that at least one visible sheet is always there - run this code on a new workbook it will fail on the last sheet as all worksheets have the word `Sheet` in them.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.EnableEvents = False`

Comment: How does this do what the question asks for?

Comment: Yes, your code works perfectly Dave, thank you very much, I only replaced "Thisworkbook" by "activeworkbook" in your code because my VBA code is located in personal.xlsb